# SNMP packet capture missing in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, snmp

I have polled asynchronously a SNMP device in a simulated network using a java file, written with SNMP API. In a 30 seconds of polling time, I have sent around 350000 V1 Get requests.

My SNMP API listener showing that all the request have been sent and got success response for each request. But when I capture the packets using wireshark, it is not showing that all the packets are sent. When I check the request id of the snmp packets in wireshark,I could able to find out that the last request's requst id is same to the total number of packets sent by SNMP API. But request id of some other SNMP packets are missing in the wireshark.

Is there any limitation to wireshark like that it can capture only a particular number of packets per second?

Why this scenario occurred? Please help me to figure out this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing any SNMP frames at all?

Comment: How many packets are missing in the capture?
35k is a fair few packages to send in only 30s so maybe wireshark cannot handle the load?

Comment: For a 1 second polling, all the packets are captured in wireshark successfully. But when the polling time is increased, packet missing is occurred. For a 30 second polling, 35k requests, wireshark missed around 3k requests. If my API showing that 35k requests was sent, the first request id in wireshark is 1 and the last request id is 35k. But in between 1 and 35k, some requests are missing in wireshark. Is there any maximum load limit in wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "simulated network"? If you are running a virtual network on your own PC then the packets will not go through your network and Wireshark will not pick them up. You can find more information and possibly a fix in the [Wireshark wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback).

Some other things to look at:

- Make sure Wireshark is capturing from the correct interface.
- Check if the packets aren't filtered out.

Comment: I captured the packets on local and any interface. Only around 3k requests are missing, other packets are getting captured

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS machine. Wireshark version is 1.6.7 with libcap version is 1.1.1

Comment: I have updated wireshark from 1.6.7 to 1.8.2 using the commands : "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install wireshark".

In this one also the libcap version is 1.1.1. Packet missing is occuring in this 1.8.2 version also, when I used the SNMP API polling java file.

Comment: When I used a script file using the netsnmp command for polling, out of 300000 requests, 287 were missing. The script file content is given below. "for (( i=1; i<=300000; i++ )) do snmpget -v 1 -c public -t 5 1.1.1.1:8001 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 done "

The request per second sent by the netsnmp script file is very much less than the request per second sent by the SNMP API java file. That may be the reason for the missing packet count is reduced for netsnmp request.

From this can I confirm that wireshark will miss packet capture for a large number of request per second?

Comment: I tried to install the wireshark 1.12.7 from www.wireshark.org, in my Ubuntu 12.04. I downloaded the source code for installation. But there was no make file present in that tar file, as said in the "https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChBuildInstallUnixBuild.html"

Can you please help me how can I install wireshark 1.12.7 in my machine?

Is that version contain the latest libcap version so that there should not be any missing packets?